# Trouble with VGA Controller on CPLD

Tags: verilog, fpga, vga

What I am attempting to do is create a VGA controller from a Lattice MachXO CPLD in Verilog.

**The Problem**

I am attempting to display the color red with a resolution of 640x480 @ 60Hz using a 25.175 MHz clock internal to the CPLD; however, when I plug the CPLD into a monitor I get an "Out of Range" message; no monitor I try can understand what resolution I would like.

**What I've tried**

I have simulated the code in ModelSim (pictures included), and everything appears to look good save for one issue. When I count the amount of time steps that have occurred from the during the V-Sync display zone (when H-Sync is drawing) and divided it by the frequency of H-Sync, I get 479 pulses -- one short of the 480 lines I should be drawing. I don't understand where this could be coming from as I've check my timings many times, and I suspect that this *may* be a symptom of the problem, but I'm not sure.

The numbers I'm using to generate my numbers for timings is from Tiny VGA: 
[tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz](http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz)

Below is my code, and pictures of the timings from ModelSim, thanks.

```
module Top(RESET, H_SYNC, V_SYNC, RED);
    input  wire RESET;
    output wire H_SYNC;
    output wire V_SYNC;
    output wire RED;

    wire rgb_en;

    /*** Test Bench Code ***/
     //reg osc_clk, reset;
     //initial begin
         //#0 reset     = 0;
         //#0 osc_clk = 0;
         //#2 reset     = 1;
     //end

     //always #1 osc_clk = ~osc_clk;

    OSCC        OSCC_1 (.OSC(osc_clk)); /*< IP clock module for Lattice CPLD    >*/
    Controller  CNTRL(.NRST(RESET), .CLK(osc_clk), .H_SYNC(H_SYNC), .V_SYNC(V_SYNC), .RGB_EN(rgb_en));

    assign RED = (rgb_en ? 1:1'bz); 

endmodule

module Controller(CLK, NRST, H_SYNC, V_SYNC, RGB_EN);
    input  wire CLK;        /*< CLK input from Top module   >*/
    input  wire NRST;       /*< Reset input from Top module >*/
    output reg  H_SYNC;     /*< Goes to VGA Horizontal Sync >*/
    output reg  V_SYNC;     /*< Goes to VGA Verical Sync    >*/
    output reg  RGB_EN  ;   /*< Enables RGB values durning display time on H_SYNC   >*/

    reg [10:0] h_counter;   /*< Tracks amount of pulses from CLK                    >*/
    reg [19:0] v_counter;   /*< Tracks amount of pulses from H_SYNC                 >*/

    `define H_SYNC_PULSE        11'd96      /*< Length of Sync Pulse            >*/
    `define H_BACK_PORCH_END    11'd144     /*< Pulse len + Porch Len           >*/
    `define H_FRONT_PORCH_STRT  11'd784     /*< Front Porch Len - Max           >*/
    `define H_COUNT_MAX         11'd799     /*< Max line pulses for resolution          >*/

    `define V_SYNC_PULSE        19'd1600
    `define V_BACK_PORCH_END    19'd28000
    `define V_FRONT_PORCH_STRT  19'd412000
    `define V_COUNT_MAX         19'd419999

    /*** State Machine for H_SYNC ***/
    always @(*) begin
        /* If the vertical sync line is not in the display zone, keep H_Sync low */
        if(!(v_counter > `V_BACK_PORCH_END && v_counter < `V_FRONT_PORCH_STRT)) begin
            H_SYNC = 0;
            RGB_EN = 0;
        end
        /* If the vertical sync line is in display zone, allow H_Sync to go through its procedure */
        else begin
            if (h_counter < `H_SYNC_PULSE) begin
                H_SYNC = 0;
                RGB_EN = 0;
            end
            /* If H_Sync is in the display zone, enable RGB */
            else if (h_counter > `H_BACK_PORCH_END && h_counter < `H_FRONT_PORCH_STRT) begin
                H_SYNC = 1;
                RGB_EN = 1;
            end
            /* During the Front Porch period, disable RGB */
            else begin
                H_SYNC = 1;
                RGB_EN = 0;
            end
        end
    end

    /*** State Machine for V_SYNC ***/
    always @(*) begin
        if (v_counter < `V_SYNC_PULSE) begin
            V_SYNC = 0;
        end
        else begin
            V_SYNC = 1;
        end
    end

    /*** Counter logic ***/
    always @(posedge CLK) begin
        if (h_counter >= `H_COUNT_MAX || !NRST) begin
            h_counter <= 11'b00;
        end
        else begin
            h_counter <= h_counter + 1;
        end
    end

    always @(posedge CLK) begin
        if (v_counter >= `V_COUNT_MAX || !NRST) begin
            v_counter <= 11'b00;
        end
        else begin
            v_counter <= v_counter + 1;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

/*< h_counter at back porch >*/
[image]

/*< Counter rollover and V_SYNC >*/
[image]

Comment: How'd you come up with the tick counts for the defines? Not saying they're wrong, but maybe adding some math to your post might help. For example if I look at the V_COUNT_MAX * your frequency I get 16.55ms (60.4Hz), while in the VGA link you provided the frame time should be 16.68ms (60Hz). Also the time between your front and back porch (408800 - 28000)/800 I think is only 476 lines, not 480.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I must have forgotten to push my code to the repo when I got home and made that post as those are old numbers. V_COUNT_MAX 's value should have been 419999 and V_FRONT_PORCH_STRT should equal 412000 which gives me a  value of 59.94Hz. I have edited the post to reflect the correct numbers and those were the only differences between my copy at the lab and at home. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every VGA monitor I've worked with requires that the red, green, and blue signals are all zero during the blanking periods `(HSYNC | VSYNC)`.  Instead of assigning to z (high impedance) try `assign RED = (rgb_en ? 1'b1 : 1'b0);`.  You would also have to do this with GREEN and BLUE as well (or just assign them to 0 permanently).

If it's not that, it is most probably a timing issue.  Try to use an oscilloscope to measure the frequency of your VSYNC signals - it should nicely line up to 60Hz.

Comment: It was indeed a timing issue. The problem was with the CPLD, at the lead of my professor, and poor documentation, I thought that the internal clock was programmable, when in fact what I was reading the margin of error. 

In the event that someone else stumbles upon this, the Lattice MachXO 2280C CPLD cannot be used to control a VGA display without an external clock. Thanks for your reply, exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Related to @exhausted_engy response (tried to make this a comment, but can't figure out where to do so): a lot of video DACs have pins for dac_blank and dac_sync for exactly this purpose.